# Run Network and Sharing center with rights of a different user

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, control-panel, non-admin

How do I change network adapter settings (i.e. change between DHCP and static IP address) while logged in as a non-administrator user, but with available credentials of an administrator user?

I have two domain accounts I use on my Windows 7 machine:  standard user and tech user.  The standard user that I log in with is not and administrator on the machine and thus doesn't have rights to change system settings.  I can get around this in most cases by running certain programs as the other user, but one thing I have not been able to do is change network settings as described above without actually logging out or switching users to the other.

I have tried running the following commands:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\techuser "control netconnections"
runas /user:DOMAIN\techuser "control /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter"
runas /user:DOMAIN\techuser control
runas /user:DOMAIN\techuser cmd --- followed by "control netconnections"
```

In all cases, when I get to the point of hitting Properties on the network adapter, it tells me that "You do not have sufficient privileges for configuring connection properties."

Is there another workaround?

Comment: Have you tried 'Runas /user:domain\user cmd', and then running `control netconnecitons` from within that newly spawned CMD prompt?

Comment: Tried it just now, same result when I try to get to the Properties screen

Comment: OK, perhaps try `runas /user:DOMAIN\techuser "%windir%\system32\ncpa.cpl"`? :)